# Excel VBA Code Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro that adds 0s to ID numbers until they are 7 numbers long. I have used it countless times before and it has always worked without fail until today it started not working and the portion of the code `For i = 1 To endrow - 1` is highlighted every time and I cannot debug the issue. The whole code is.

```
Sub AddZeroes()

'Declarations
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, endrow As Long
'Converts the A column format to Text format
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'finds the bottom most row
endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'selects the top cell in column A
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

'loop to move from cell to cell
For i = 1 To endrow - 1
    'Moves the cell down 1. Assumes there's a header row so really starts at row 2
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'The Do-While loop keeps adding zeroes to the front of the cell value until it hits a length of 7
    Do While Len(ActiveCell.Value) < 7
        ActiveCell.Value = "0" & ActiveCell.Value
    Loop
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of **endrow** at the point it stops? also, if the format is for display purposes only, then the whole routine can be replaced with `Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "0000000"`

Comment: The endrow portion is to tell it stop on the very last row, normally it would go one extra row down and add a cell with just 7 0s. the -1 tells it stop on the very last cell.

Comment: when the code gets highlighted to indicate an error, what it the value of **endrow** at that point?

Comment: depends on what the ID number is really

Comment: Does it error out on every ID number now? is the `endrow` different every time it errors out? what is an example error value?

Comment: It does the first number and adds all the 0s then the rest it doesnt touch. In this case the final number is over 7 digits long already but that has never been an issue.

Comment: But what is the value of `endrow` when you get the error??

Comment: You *really* should not use `.Select` for VBA routines like this.  Besides being very slow, it can cause many strange and unexpected side-effects.  Turning off ScreenUpdating does not, in general, fix this.  The answer by Floris is a good example of how to do this without having to use `.Select`.

Comment: Could it be that cell A1 is blank - in that case your .End(xlDown) statement will only select cells A1:A2... At any rate the answer I gave below gives some examples of a cleaner way to achieve this. Did you try it - does it give the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what is causing the error - but would suggest another approach:

```
sub addZeros()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' start at row 2 since OP said there's a header row

  Dim c as Range
  for each c in Range("A2", [A2].End(xlDown))
    c.Value = "'" & Format(c.Value, "00000000")
  next c
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```

A bit more compact...

Note that I'm adding the "'" apostrophe to make Excel treat the cell value as string. This is a safe way to make sure the zeros stay...

EDIT: Got rid of the last .Select to show it can be done, and is generally good practice as pointed out in comments.

Comment: +1: for getting rid of most of the .Select and Active* references

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung . I can get rid of the last select with `for each c in Range("A2",[A2].End(xlDown))` . That would be even shorter and cleaner.